# Is it possible to update Chrome WebDriver options?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to change Chrome WebDriver ChromeOptions/Capabilities after creation of the WebDriver object?

```
Map<String, Object> preferences = new HashMap<String, Object>();
preferences.put("download.default_directory", "C:/downloads/");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", preferences);

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

// do some stuff with the driver
// is it possible to change the default download directory here?
```

**EDIT 1:**
I have few hundred subpages on my website, each of them has few attachments. I would like to create the tree of the directories (each directory contains files connected only to this specific subpage).

Comment: why can't you do that in the first place?? instead of setting it to 'C:/downloads/'!!

Comment: Hi @Ranjith's, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Once you set the chromedriver options, its fixed to the driver instance, so it cannot be changed. An approach to going about this, will be to tear down the instance and create a new one with the updated path.